# how to get the list of use images in website page using curl

Tags: linux, curl

How to get all available images of website page.

Here I am getting the all html code of webpage using curl:

```
curl http://www.xyztest.com
```

How I can get the list of used images in this webpage?

Comment: Do you want to **extract** all `img` tags from a html page, or do you want to **download** all images from a html page?

Comment: I want only list of available images in that webpage without downloading it;.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can show example with `wget`. Let's try to get list with all images and then (if needed) download all images from [this site](https://www.pexels.com/)

1) Download index page with wget

```
wget -k https://www.pexels.com/
```

`k` option (very important) is used to convert local links to global.

2) Now we will mine needed information. First, filter throw `grep img` to get only rows with `<img>` tag. Second grep uses regexp to get links addresses. `sed` cuts arguments in links after `?` character. Finally, save our links to links.txt

```
cat index.html | grep img | grep -Po 'src="\K.*?(?=")' | sed 's/\?.*//' > links.txt
```

3) Now we can easily download all images with

```
wget -i links.txt
```

You can download and process the links with a single set of pipes, using `curl` instead as requested:

```
curl https://www.pexels.com/ | grep img | grep -o src="\"http.*" | grep -o "http.*\"" | sed 's/\?.*//' > links.txt
```

Comment: The `img` tag could span over multiple lines.

Comment: Can you please suggest the fix?

Comment: You could remove newlines inside of the img like this: `tr '\n' ' ' | tr '>' '\n'`